accursed [əkɜːrsid][əkɚst] Which one is more prevalent?

The word 'accursed' is showing two methods of pronunciation: [əkɜːrsid], [əkɚst]

If you are a US English speaker or BR. speaker, would there be any difference?

Most people don't say accursed in standard conversation. It would be more common to hear "cursed" without the prefix. It typically comes up in fiction like fantasy books or old plays. In AmE (can't speak to BrE), [əkɚst] is the "modern" pronunciation. Saying [əkɜːrsid] gives a very specific archaic or dramatized tone. Someone performing Shakespeare /might/ use [əkɜːrsid], or maybe a child pretending they are very fancy in medieval times.

Thx, but what did you mean by 'fancy'?

Or someone humorously using mock-archaic language.

Cambridge says both are used in the UK, but /əˈkɝːst/ is the only US pronunciation. Not sure if that's 100% true or more of a generalization.

I wouldn't waste time on accursed. As this usage chart shows, it's no longer used enough for even native speakers to think about how best to pronounce it. The full OED says it's Now somewhat archaic and literary.

In contemporary American English, trisyllabic accurséd is a synonym for "damned" and is used primarily when swearing about something:

This accurséd car won't start in cold weather!

I don't think it's used much by people who were born  in the 1970s or after.
